# What are the molecular/cellular basis of pruritus ?

Tags: human-biology, physiology

Could someone please explain the cells and molecules involved in the clinical phenomenon of **pruritus** ?
I'm interested in a general view about the subject, but detailed answers will be appreciated.

Comment: Molecular basis:  histamine.